# what is the best way to send phone(s) location from a mobile app to the server?

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, geolocation

I have web app that should receive phones location in real time from mobile app and display them on google Map. Obviously, if the phone moves , I want to show that the phone is moving in real time on the map

web app:
front end: reactjs,
backend: Nodejs,
database :MYSQL,

Mobile app:
flutter

I will have around 70-80 mobile users who will send their locations in real time to my web app

1. How to send the location of the phone to the server?
2. What is the best way to handle all these locations on my web application ?

Please take into your consideration my application performance and scalability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what sampling you need and what you plan to use it for.
WS is the way to go.

If you plan to store the data then for scalability I suggest a nonSQL approach (Firebase is a good suggestion).

Comment: I see I think I am going to use firebase but I have a question. 

can I use firebase and MYSQL together in my project ? I use firebase only for locations and I use MYSQL for the rest of my data.

Comment: @UnderJunge I have a similar question. What is WS? Could you expand on your answer to give more detail about how to periodically send the location of the phone a server? Some more specific implementation details would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase , it's will provide you Realtime Database and other cool features which are very good for performance , also you can use it's feature of hosting your website,  it's both compatible to mobile app development and web development , in your Flutter , React and Node.js   ,
https://firebase.google.com/
The Mobile app will send the location Co-ordinates of your Location to Firebase ReadlTime Database,

```
         https://pub.dev/packages/location
```

then you can access the location from your React web app simply by calling  firebase API function for JS

```
        https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#node.js
```

Comment: Thank you for your response

1) Do I send the location as http request every ten seconds or I use web socket ?

2) Can I use mysql? I am not really familiar with Firebase

3) can I send only the locations to firebase and save the rest of my data to MySQl